# Visual Studio 2015 Xamarin pending to install updates don't install

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

I run visual studio 2015 as an administrator

I update Xamarin from tools->options->Xamarin

After I download the updates I get this

[image]

**When I click install nothing happens!**

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the contents of "\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\MonoDevelop-4.0\Cache\TempDownload" and then check again for updates